# Nested forms creates empty instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a Post and a MaterielLink models.
A post `has_many materiel_links`, and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :materiel_links`

I use the gem cocoon to create a nested form: on the post form, I want to be able to add links that will be created on submit of the form.

post/new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :html => { :id => "post_form", "data-post-id" => @post.id } do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :materiel_links do |materiel_link| %>
    <%= render 'materiel_link_fields', f: materiel_link %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_association 'Ajouter', f, :materiel_links%> 
<% end %>
```

_materiel_link_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.fields_for :materiel_links do |materiel_link| %>
  <%= materiel_link.text_field :name %>
  <%= materiel_link.text_field :link %>
<% end %>
```

In my post controller:

```
 def update
    @materiel_links = @post.materiel_links.build(post_params[:materiel_links_attributes]

    if @post.update!(post_params)
      session[:current_draft_post_id] = nil
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

I am here in the update action since, for reasons specific to my rails app, the post is created when the posts/new page is rendered (It is created empty, and the user just updates it instead of actually creating it). So the post already exists, but not the materiel_links that I have to create in the update action.

And the params:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, materiel_links_attributes: [:name,:link] )
end
```

I added a `raise` in the update action, and what is stange is that I can find the link/name for each materiel_link I've added when I type `params` but with a number before each couple:

```
>> params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"wqzWfaAcwrOOdxViYBO5HaV2bwsNsf5HsvDFEbBYapkOMAPXOJR7oT4zQHbc/hTW8T9a+iH5NRl1WUApxrIjkA==", "post"=>{"title"=>"my title", "materiel_links_attributes"=>{"1459431927732"=>{"materiel_links"=>{"name"=>"mon Lien 1", "link"=>"htttp1"}}, "1459431933881"=>{"materiel_links"=>{"name"=>" Mon lien 2", "link"=>"htttp2"}}}}, "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1250"}
```

But nothing in the materiel_links hashes when I type `post_params`:

```
>> post_params
=> {"title"=>"my title","materiel_links_attributes"=>{"1459431927732"=>{}, "1459431933881"=>{}}}
```

The instances of MaterielLink are created, but they are empty: they don't save the link/name.

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Does a `materiel_link have_many materiel_links`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that because in your update action you used `.build` before `.update`, it somehow conflicted with `.update` because the materiel_links values are passed there once again. You do not need to build in `update` action anymore; but only in `edit` action, because the materiel_links will be automatically created/updated when `.update(post_params)` is called, as post_params already include `materiel_links` values. Try

```
def update
  if @post.update!(post_params)
    @materiel_links = @post.materiel_links

    session[:current_draft_post_id] = nil
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You'd also need whitelist the ID of materiel_link in strong params, so that these materiel_links in the form can be updated (ID not needed  to be whitelisted if just create, and no update). You might also want to allow destroy. Update into the following:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, materiel_links_attributes: [:id, :name, :link, :_destroy] )
end

# post.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :materiel_links, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have specified that for reasons specific to my rails app, the post is created when the posts/new page is rendered (it is empty), so the user only updates it. That's why I use the update action and not create. And, since the post was created, but not the materiel_links, shouldn't I use .new or .build in the update action ?

Comment: The `.build` creates a placeholder association object. It does not yet persist to the DB. It also is only stored in the memory. Most of the time, you only use `.build` inside the actions `new` and `edit`. The reason for this is that `.build` builds the object into the memory after that line is called (let's say .build is called in `edit` action), after which `edit` template is rendered. But in that `edit.html.erb`, the fields_for already generates the fields for the "built" object. After clicking submit button, the params will now include the "built" object, ready to be finally saved in the DB